# Unable to access pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

when I am executing command `bin/pyspark` from the path where spark has been installed I am getting the error

```
-bash: bin/pyspark: No such file or directory
```

I tried to build spark using command sbt/sbt assembly. This one also went on error with message

```
-bash: sbt/sbt: No such file or directory
```

I am able to access scala by executing command `bin/spark-shell` from the same path.

I am using Red Hat 4.4.5-6.

Below is a screen shot of bin folder and error messages.

[image: Screen shot of /usr/lib/spark/bin]

Comment: How did you get the Spark distribution?  Git clone, source code or binary download from http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html?

Comment: No clue. The person who had installed spark is no more in the organization. Any way of finding it out? I did not find any tar file related to spark. So I am guessing it was not a binary download from spark.apache.org/downloads.html, though my assumption may be wrong.